Source of compensation in an accident Involving an under-insured motorist
Background

I was the victim of an auto accident and the other driver was found to be 100% at fault.
The other driver's auto insurance bodily injury liability coverage and property
damage liability coverage are much less than what I have with my auto
insurance company.
Their coverage is insufficient to compensate me for my economic damages, let alone non-economic damages (e.g., pain and suffering).
As a result of this fact, I’ve filed a claim against my under-insured motorist coverage that I have with my auto insurance company.

Let’s say the other driver’s policy has bodily injury (B.I.) liability coverage of $25 and property damage (P.D.) liability coverage of $25.
My policy was issued for the state of Virginia. Let’s say my policy’s under-insured motorist bodily injury coverage is $100 and my under-insured motorist property damage coverage is $100.
As I understand it, because it’s a Virginia policy, my auto insurance company cannot reduce the limits (i.e., get credit) of my under-insured motorist coverage by the amount I can or will get from the other driver’s auto insurance company. In other words, If the sum of my economic and non-economic B.I. and P.D. damages is $250, then I’d expect $50 of it to come from the other driver’s auto insurance company, and $200 of it to come from my auto insurance company.
If the sum of my economic and non-economic B.I. and P.D. damages is $300, then I can claw back $250, and then either sue the other driver directly for the remaining $50, or just eat it.
Does this analysis sound correct?

FWIW, the nitty gritty details of uninsured and underinsured motorist coverage including calculation of the amount owed is very technical and very involved (no way you could know that). In Colorado, where I practice, maybe a third of all appellate cases on personal injury and insurance law at the state supreme court level and maybe 20% of PI and insurance law cases it at the intermediate appellate court level, involve uninsured and underinsured motorist coverage. While the general concepts are fairly similar from state to state, many details vary by state, even at the level of this question.

@ohwilleke you know the other driver is responsible since it is a hypothetical

Continues . . .  all of which is to say that I won't provide an answer to this question because I wouldn't trust myself to identify all of the legal sub-issues and resolve them correctly in VA, or even in CO (I've done about two UIM cases almost twenty years ago and one more more recently with less complex facts as the at fault teen driver had no insurance, no assets, and no income). For example, one whole dimension of the analysis not identified in the question but which is important are the insurance company's subrogation rights and how those interact with your ability to sue directly.

@Tak The other driver's being "at fault" isn't one of the things that makes it complicated.

What insurance would be state legal and not cover the damage to the property though?

@Tak: I think the amounts in the question are arbitrary; multiply them by 1000 and you'd have plausible numbers where the at-fault driver's liability insurance ($25K/$25K) might be legal and yet not be able to cover the property damage or bodily injury.  In fact, it looks like Virginia allows a person to drive with no insurance at all if they pay a $500 annual fee to the state.

Oh, but this will end on July 1, and insurance will be mandatory.
